# Angular-cli ng serve livereload not working

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I have created a sample project wiht Ng-cli, then i run ng serve in the source folder, the project loads correctly in the browser but livereload not working.

npm -v : 3.10.9

ng -v:
 angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3
 node: 4.4.3
 os: win32 x64

Already searched a lot information on internet, and nothing solved the issue.

Answer (score 85):

I faced with the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 and angular CLI 1.0.0.

The problem was related with Inotify Watches Limit on Linux.
To solve the issue, I increased the watches limit to 512K.
Run these commands.

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sudo sysctl -p --system
```

After that, I restarted my IDE, and after that, the change detection started to work.

Comment: Although, the OP asked about win :P, the answered help me as I use Ubuntu 18 and Angular CLI 6.0.3. Thanks a lot!

Comment: for me restarting my terminal helped after these changes

Answer (score 34):

> ### Increasing the amount of inotify watchers
>
> **The technical details**
>
> Listen uses inotify by default on Linux to monitor directories for
>   changes. It's not uncommon to encounter a system limit on the number
>   of files you can monitor. For example, Ubuntu Lucid's (64bit) inotify
>   limit is set to 8192.
>
> You can get your current inotify file watch limit by executing:
>
> ```
> $ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
> ```
>
> When this limit is not enough to monitor all files inside a directory,
>   the limit must be increased for Listen to work properly.
>
> You can set a new limit temporary with:
>
> ```
> $ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
> $ sudo sysctl -p
> ```
>
> If you like to make your limit permanent, use:
>
> ```
> $ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
> $ sudo sysctl -p
> ```
>
> You may also need to pay attention to the values of
>   `max_queued_events` and `max_user_instances` if Listen keeps on complaining.

[Source](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)

Answer (score 5):

Try `ng serve -lr` flag. This flag works with me.
Probably the issue occurs becuase --live-reload flag is deprecated

Comment: `ng serve --live-reload -o` angular cli 8.x.x

Answer (score 4):

It due to the webpack.

If we running two angular application at a time.
Sometimes, it may not reload application every time we need to stop and start application. **For that case run one application at a time**.

Answer (score 2):

Is your project on a mapped network drive? I found that this caused LiveReload to fail.

Running on VS Code on Windows 7.
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
NPM: 5.6.0
OS: win32 x64

I created a barebones Angular app with Angular CLI on my 'E:' drive, which is mapped to a folder on my network.  'ng serve' does NOT detect code changes. I copied the project to my 'C:' drive and Live Reload works as expected. So see if moving your project to a local drive solves your problem.

Comment: This is exactly the issue im facing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

On **Linux OS** run your app with administrative controls using `sudo`

```
sudo ng serve
```

Comment: a nice solution thnx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of what's the issue with your version, but recently I faced the similar issue. Here is my machine environment :
`Ubuntu: 16.04.3
npm -v : 5.5.1

ng -v : 
Angular CLI: 1.5.5
Node: 9.2.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.0.4`

I was using `ng serve -o` to serve the files locally,and this was some how causing the problem for live-reload, what fixed the problem was `ng serve --open`  instead.Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Live reload server stopped working after upgrade to Angular 7.

The reason is my Node version was 10.15.0. on Windows 10 x64.

After downgrade Node to version 10.10.0 -> everything is working fine now.

You can download older Node versions from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` to this file `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Or run this `sudo echo “fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288” >> /etc/sysctl.conf`. Should also work if you don’t want to open the file and edit it.

Then run this `sudo sysctl -p --system`