# why ng serve is not auto compiling after saving the files in ubuntu vs code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows and ng serve in Visual Studio Code is not auto compiling the code after every save.

I have to stop the terminal and fire the command again to compile my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng serve not detecting file changes automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092880/ng-serve-not-detecting-file-changes-automatically)

Comment: Yes the problem is same however the answer there is difficult to find for which I created a separate thread to answer the question effectively.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366212/angular-cli-ng-serve-livereload-not-working, which has an answer quoting the exact same article as you

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the alike questions . will try to search more effectively before creating new thread. @jonrsharpe

Comment: `ng serve --poll=2000` , the reason is just that vs code does not have permission try running vs code as root

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092880/ng-serve-not-detecting-file-changes-automatically  check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Listen uses inotify by default on Linux to monitor directories for
>   changes. It's not uncommon to encounter a system limit on the number
>   of files you can monitor. For example, Ubuntu Lucid's (64bit) inotify
>   limit is set to 8192.
>
> You can get your current inotify file watch limit by executing:
>
> ```
> $ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
> ```
>
> When this limit is not enough to monitor all files inside a
>   directory, the limit must be increased for Listen to work properly.
>
> You can set a new limit temporary with:
>
> ```
> $ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
> $ sudo sysctl -p
> ```
>
> If you like to make your limit permanent, use:
>
> ```
> $ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> $ sudo sysctl -p
> ```

Source: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

Answer (score 0):

some time auto refreshes not working so you can be forcing ng serve command using sudo before the command.
 like: **sudo ng serve**.

after that, you would not need compiling the code after every saves.