# Angular LiveReload not working with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: angular, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have wanted to leverage WSL for some time now so I recently changed my Intellij terminal to an Ubuntu Bash shell. Since then, I cannot get LiveReload to work correctly. Saving the project triggers a re-compilation and everything looks to have been updated, but the changes are not served.

I have tried increasing the limit of watches in my `inotify` settings as suggested here: [Angular-cli ng serve livereload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366212/angular-cli-ng-serve-livereload-not-working)

I also upgraded my Angular version, my node version, and anything else I could think of. My file path to the directory does not contain any spaces or invalid characters, as per another suggestion here: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610

I tried removing `node_modules` and doing a fresh install. I tried passing explicit live reload flags on the `ng serve` command, and increasing the poll time. I tried running with `sudo`.

I did see some mention of LiveReload not working with mapped network drives, and I'm wondering if trying to run `ng serve` out of the WSL mounted drives is causing the issue, so I will try that next, but after that I'm all out of ideas.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue with you.

Comment: Well, not exactly the same setup, but in my case LiveReload (Chrome extension) can't connect to Spring Boot running under WSL 2. Will be nice, if someone finds a solution, to share it.

Comment: Maybe to late, but I fixed it using `ng serve --poll=2000`

The other way is not to use mounted drive...